# Hilbert polynomial Twisted cubic

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $C$ the twisted cubic in $\mathbb{P}^3$ defined as $V(XZ-Y^2, YW-Z^2,XW-YZ)$. I have to calculate Hilbert polynomial of $C$, that I denote $P_C(n)$. In order to calculate Hilber polynomials in general, I consider the exact twisted sequence
$$ 0 \to \mathcal{I}_C(n) \to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(n) \to \mathcal{O}_C(n) \to 0 .$$
If $C=V(F)$, where $deg(F)=m$ I use the isomophism $\mathcal{I}_C \simeq \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(n-m)$ given by the multiplication for $C$. In this situation I don't know how to use this way in order to calculate Hilbert polynomial of the twisted cubic.

Answer (score 9):

As I explained it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/573817/hilbert-polynomial-of-an-hypersurface-in-projective-space/573943#573943) one way is to first find the Hilbert function $h_C(d)$ and see what polynomial it is when $d \gg 0.$

Let $H=\{w=0\} \subset \mathbb{P}^3$ and consider $X=C \cap H=V(w,xz-y^2,z^2,yz).$ Then the homogeneous coordinate ring of $X$ is (isomorphic to) $S(X)=k[x,y,z]/(xz-y^2,z^2,yz).$

*Exercise*: Show that its degree $d$ part, $S(X)^{(d)},$ is generated by $x^d,x^{d-1}y, x^{d-1}z$ as a vector space over $k,$ and conclude that $h_X(d)=\dim_k S(X)^{(d)}=3,$ so is $p_X(d)=3.$

Now the question is, how to relate $C$ and $X?$

The answer is the following SES

$$0\longrightarrow k[x,y,z,w]/I \stackrel{.w}{\longrightarrow} k[x,y,z,w]/I \longrightarrow k[x,y,z,w]/(I+(w)) \longrightarrow 0$$

where $I=(y^2-xz,z^2-yw,xw-yz).$ (It would be easy to run the cohomological approach if you like, using this SES.)

Take the $d$ graded pieces of the SES to get $h_C(d)=h_C(d-1)+h_X(d)$ and note that $h_C(0)=1,$ since $S(C)^{(0)}=k.$ Finally, prove that $h_C(d)=3d+1$ which is a polynomial, thus $p_C(d)=3d+1.$

In general, the degree of the Hilbert polynomial of a projective subscheme $X$ of $\mathbb{P}^n$ coincides with the dimension of $X$, so there should be no surprise that why in this case is a degree one polynomial.

Moreover, the *degree of* $X$ is defined to be $(\dim X)! \times \text{leading coefficient of} \; p_X(d),$ which in our case is $3.$

Comment: I don't know how to do your exercize... Actually, if $d=1$ $S(X)^{(d)}$ is generated by $x,y,z$ but if $d>1$ how can I do it?

Comment: Dear @ArthurStuart, for $d>1,$ take an element in $k[x,y,z]/(xz-y^2,z^2,yz)$ and note that the representing polynomial cannot have $z^2$ or $yz$ in it since $z^2=0=yz.$ Moreover, you can replace $y^2$ by $xz,$ since $xz=y^2$ in the quotient ring. Argue why any element in the quotient ring can be generated by those three elements. I think, you should be able to continue from here.

Answer (score 9):

When $n$ is large, the value of the Hilbert polynomial is just the dimension of $H^0(C,\mathcal O_C(n) ).$

By definition $C$ is a copy of $\mathbb P^1$, embedded with degree $3$, and so $\mathcal O_C(1)$ is a degree $3$ line bundle on $C$.  Thus $\mathcal O_C(n)$ has degree $3n$, and the dimension of global sections of a degree $3n$ line bundle on $\mathbb P^1$ is $3n + 1$.  (Just the number of polys. in one variable of degree at most $3n$.)

So the Hilbert poly. is equal to $3n + 1$.

---

In general, a degree $d$ curve of genus $g$ (in any projective space) will have
Hilbert poly. equal to $d n + 1 - g$.

Comment: Thank you... but I don't know two things: 1) why if the degree of embedding is $3$, then $deg(\mathcal{O}_C(1))=3$ (for me the degree of a line bundles is the first Chern class...) 2) why if $deg(\mathcal{O}_C(1)=3)$ then $deg(\mathcal{O}_C(n))=3n$. Thank you very much in advance!